# share attributes between classes in C++

Tags: c++, class, attributes

Assuming, I have a class with many attributes

```
class A {
private:
    int x1;
    int x2;
    ....
    int xn;
}
```

I want share some group attributes with other class. Example `class B`, `class C`, ... that `class B` can access `x1, x3` for set/get, class C can access `x1, x2, xn` for set/get.

My solution:

**Solution 1**: `class A` is singleton. If `class B` or `class C` want to set/get attribute in `class A` use `A::GetInstance()` (for example) to set/get attribute. With this solution, you don't care what attribute that `class B` (or `class C`) is shared. With my opinion, using **singleton** must be careful with multi-thread problem.

**Solution 2** I use class to shared.

Example

```
class SharedB {
public
    int x1;
    int x3;
}

class SharedC {
public
    int x1;
    int x2;
    int xn;
}
```

`class SharedB` and `class SharedC` also will be **singleton** that `class B` and `class C` can use. The advantage of this solution that is i can control what i share. But disadvantage is also use singleton that i think not safe with multi-thread.

So my question is have solution for my problem that's **better** and **thread-safe**.

Thank for your answer.

Comment: Wrong approach, you don't need a singleton but an [Abstract Class](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/abstract_class). If you can't design such class, your design is wrong.

Comment: Is the [tag:c] tag added for a specific reason ....?

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi: thank, i will think about Abstract Class.

Comment: I see 3 different questions: common data, data access mode and thread-safety. Probably the topic should be reformulated.